Bash - Having trouble with the find command and excluding paths
Short background; I have a script I run to put new TV episodes into my library after conversion and naming. It just locates the matching directory by name. Recently I fsck'd my drives, and it warned me I was missing lost+found, and recreated it. Now my old script throws a warning (but works).
Old command:
find -L ../ -name "$show" -not -path "../To Sort/*"

It gets run on each directory within To Sort, and searches through all the other directories in the parent directory of To Sort.
Old Error:

find: ‘../lost+found’: Permission denied

In searching for a way to stop it trying lost+found, I learned that -not -path isn't the right way to use that, and I should be using -prune; so I tried a few times to make a new one, but this is as far as I got:
found="$(find -L ../ \( -path "../To Sort" -o -path "../lost+found" \) -prune -o \ ../ -name "$show" )"

And now errors:

find: paths must precede expression: ` ../'


Well, there's that spurious \ ../ in the middle which doesn't make sense. You're also missing a -print to avoid the global default -print action which would also apply to the pruned paths:
found="$(
  find -L .. '(' -path '../To Sort' -o -path ../lost+found ')' -prune -o \
             -name "$show" -print
)"

The \ above at the end of the line is for line continuation to break down that long line into two to improve legibility; before any character other than newline \ acts a quoting operator, so before space like in your code, it would make it a literal space character.
But, with that code, the matching paths will end up concatenated with newline characters in between into a scalar variable. It would make more sense to store them in an array.
If using bash 4.4 or newer:
readarray -td '' files < <(
  find -L .. '(' -path '../To Sort' -o -path '../lost+found' ')' -prune -o \
             -name "$show" -print0
)

Note the -print0 instead of -print (and corresponding -d '' for readarray to split on NULs) so file paths are delimited using NUL bytes, the only byte value that cannot occur in a file path.
Then you can pass the elements of that array to a command such as ls with:
ls -ld -- "${files[@]}"

Or report the number of matches with:
echo "${#files[@]} match${files[1]+es} found"

Also beware that -name takes a pattern. If you want an exact match and the name of your show may contain wildcard characters such as ?, *, \ or [...], you'd need to escape them by prefixing them with a \.
With zsh instead of bash, you can also do:
set -o extendedglob
files=( ../{,^To\ Sort/***/}$show(N) )

Which gets expanded first to:
files=( ../$show(N) ../^To\ Sort/***/$show(N) )

And then each glob expanded separately though in a nullglob fashion with the N qualifier, so you'll get ../$show if it exists + all the ones below subdirectories of .. other than To Sort in a recursive descent that follows symlinks like with your find -L.
There, $show is not taken as a pattern and you get a sorted list and the hidden files are automatically skipped. Passing the list to a command is also simpler: ls -ld -- $files. As well as getting the count: $#files à la csh (though ${#files[@]} à la ksh also works). Also, arrays indexes, like in most other shells, start at 1 instead of 0, so you need echo $#files match${files[2]+es} found for the es for plural to be appended if the second element is set.
